# Creating a .p12 file with a KeyStore

Tags: java, encryption, certificate, pkcs#12

I have an external service that creates certificate for me, out of which I recieve a buffer (String). I attempt to load this buffer into a KeyStore in Java and then use the "store" function in order to create a .p12 file. However, the store function throws an exception - "Given final block not properly padded".

No matter what I try, I cannot get this to work or find the cause of the issue.

My code is :

```
    public void createP12Certificate(String userName, String comment) throws KeyStoreException, AdminCertificateException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException
{
    KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

    /* Some Code that gets 'buff' etc. */

    byte[] byteBuff = hexStringToByteArray(buff);
    Arrays.reverse(byteBuff);
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteBuff);
    store.load(inputStream, password.toCharArray());
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(userName+".p12");
    store.store(outputStream,anotherPassword); //Throws Exception
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: which is the format you are receiveng content? a combination of hexStringToByteArray and Arrays.reverse is very strange

Comment: I am trying to to duplicate a code that currently runs on C#, and thus has access to .net functions, in Java. Both Java and C# use an external web-service which provides a buffer (the content of the certificate). Since this is a hex-string and a KeyStore expects a byte array, I need to use hexStringToByteArray. If I do not reverse the byte array, Java throws an exception in the "load" method - that the data is not in PKCS12 format. C# reverses the byte array, so I reversed it as well. Java no longer throws an exception in "load", but now it throws one in "store" as I described.

Comment: It is possible that Hex conversions -> bytes-> reverse in C # and java not behave the same. I suggest that you make sure the format returned by the server, for example with a text editor that supports conversions hex-bytes as Notepad ++. Without seeing the file I can not help more

Answer (score 2):

The issue is at those lines

```
/* Some Code that gets 'buff' etc. */
byte[] byteBuff = hexStringToByteArray(buff);
```

Because the other posted code would work without an exception.

```
char[] passwordChars = "password".toCharArray();
String fileOne = "/tmp/output_1.p12";
String fileTwo = "/tmp/output_2.p12";

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream(fileOne), passwordChars);

keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
byte[] byteBuff = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileOne));
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteBuff);
keyStore.load(inputStream, passwordChars);
keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream(fileTwo), passwordChars);
```